# How to make UITableViewCell read out a UIImageView automatically the way it does for UILabel with voice over

Tags: ios, accessibility, voice

I've tried adding random labels to a UITableViewCell and the accessibility voice over system reads all of them automatically.

I'm also trying to add a UIImageView as an accesibility element and would like it to be read automatically with the cell as well.  It's basically a little status icon.

I set the accessibilityLabel on the image.

I also set isAccessibilityElement to YES

Right now it treats the image as a separate object.  I can select the image and or swipe left and right to read it separately instead of it being read with the cell.

Returning it in a custom accessibilityLabel getter for the cell should work too, but I'd like to use the automatic solution as much as possible.  Is there some property to set on the UIImageView to have it act like a UILabel and be automatically read as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options, one is a bit unclean, being create a label that is hidden with the same text and read through that.

I think the cleaner option for you is to maybe subclass ImageView and just give it a text or label property and have the accessibility voice just read over that instead.

Comment: I do like this solution more than other's I've thought of since it keeps the automatic behavior built into iOS.  I think I'll do something like this for now.


I feel like there's gotta be some property or config that needs to happen to make UIImageView act just like a UILabel to the accessibility system.